# How to run a Rust GTK app in IntellIJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, rust-cargo, meson-build

I have been using the following GTK Rust template - https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/Rust/gtk-rust-template

Has anyone got any experience running this using IntelliJ IDEA with the Rest plugin? Because of the various .gresource etc. files doing a pure Cargo build is not possible, and instead, it uses Meson to orchestrate the build. Any advice on how to make it work?